# How to extract WinZip Self-Extracting exe in silent mode

Tags: installation, self-extracting, winzip

I have create a exe file using WinZip Self-Extractor. It extracts the file in UI mode, that is while dobule click the setup a new window opened that shows unzipping setupname.exe. I need to extract the same exe in silent mode which should not show unzipping UI info.

Is it possible to extract the exe using WinZip Self-Extractor in **both UI mode and Silent mode**? Please share the steps if available to do this.

Comment: What happens if you run your exe with the "/?" command? Are you shown a 'usage' dialog, or given a list of command-line options in a shell window?

Answer (score 3):

For WinZip you can use the `/auto` flag followed by the directory you would like to unzip it to.

For example:

```
myWinZipSelfExtract.exe /auto C:\whereever\you\want
```

where `myWinZipSelfExtract.exe` is your self-extracting exe

Source: http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/115/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the switch -info to see the /auto command in self-extrator.

For example :

```
myWinZipSelfExtract.exe -info
```

You get for example the prompt info with the command :

```
-win32 -le -overwrite -c ".\setup.exe"
```

[Prompt info command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YChA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but found Powershells Expand-Archive command worked.

e.g. `Expand-Archive C:\\path_to_exe.exe -DestinationPath C:\\path_to_extract_to -Force`

Comment: Weird ... "Expand-Archive : .exe is not a supported archive file format. .zip is the only supported archive file format."

Comment: For me it worked only after changing the file extension of the archive from `exe` to `zip`. After renaming the file `Expand-Archive` extracted it without complaining.

Answer (score -1):

This extracts the self-extracting exe file's content in silent mode.

Syntax: `<self-extract-exe-name>.exe -unzipDir <Destination-Folder>`

Example: `Test.exe -unzipDir C:\my-files\test`