# Program for Chocolatey package not have silent installation mode

Tags: silent-installer, chocolatey

### 1. Summary

I want to create Chocolatey package for [**The Wonderful Icon**](http://www.thewonderfulicon.com/index.html) program, [**official download page**](http://www.thewonderfulicon.com/download.html). But I can not install this program in silent mode.

Yes, The Wonderful Icon — old program, but it [**perfectly work in my Windows 10**](https://superuser.com/a/1161276/572069).

---

---

### 2. Not helped

The Wonderful Icon — not my program, I don't know installer for it.

1. I install and run [**Universal Silent Switch Finder**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ussf) program as recommend [**Chocolatey manual**](https://chocolatey.org/docs/CreatePackagesQuickStart). Universal Silent Switch Finder show, that executable file of The Wonderful Icon is «Self-Extracting WinZip archive»:

[image: USSF]

I [**find**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263408/5951529) in [**Stack Overflow answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11989421/5951529) that for Self-Extracting WinZip archive we can use `/auto` flag. But it not helped for me.

2. I try to use different flags — `/S`, `/s`, `-s`, `/VERYSILENT`, `-q`, but I have not success.

---

---

### 3. Settings

[**My chocolateyinstall.ps1 file**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaChocolatey/blob/master/packages/The%20Wonderful%20Icon/tools/chocolateyinstall.ps1):

```powershell
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';

$packageName= 'The Wonderful Icon'
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$url        = 'http://www.thewonderfulicon.com/wondicon.exe'
$url64      = ''

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $packageName
  unzipLocation = $toolsDir
  fileType      = 'exe'
  url           = $url
  url64bit      = $url64

  softwareName  = 'The Wonderful Icon*'

  checksum      = ''
  checksumType  = 'sha256'
  checksum64    = ''
  checksumType64= 'sha256'

  silentArgs   = '/auto'
}

Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

---

---

### 4. Questions

1. May I install The Wonderful Icon in silent mode in Chocolatey?
2. If no, may I add package in Chocolatey without silent installation mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Not helped
>
>    I find in Stack Overflow answers that for Self-Extracting WinZip archive we can use /auto flag. But it not helped for me.

This is what makes Windows installers so much like the wild west. It's not always easy to find the silent installation arguments. And it may not even exist.

> 4. Questions
>
> May I install The Wonderful Icon in silent mode in Chocolatey?

Yes, you absolutely can have the program available in an unattended fashion with Chocolatey. There are multiple methods of working to get an unattended install, some are better than others.

From best to worst:

1. Work with installer's silent arguments
2. Find ways to set registry keys, files, or hidden tricks to ensure a program is silent on install, upgrade, and uninstall.
3. Repackage the software installer as an MSI using a tool designed for this (requires distribution rights for a public repository like Chocolatey).
4. Find the runtime binaries and use them instead (requires distribution
   rights for any public repository like Chocolatey.org).
5. Use something like AHK (AutoHotKey) or AutoIT to work around the programs inability to be silent. AHK/AutoIT should be considered a last resort when nothing else will work.

If you have distribution rights, then I might order it 1, 4, 3, 2, 5.

> If no, may I add package in Chocolatey without silent installation mode?

If you are asking if you can add this to the community package repository, aka https://chocolatey.org/packages, then it is probably better to ask that question in the "Open Chat" window that you see in the bottom right hand corner of the site.

Comment: ferventcoder, may you show real examples, how you or others Chocolatey maintainers solved silent mode problem? Thanks.